# Why do we use `const` for strings when defining with pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, constants

> For defining arrays with pointers, we write
>   `int *const a;`
>   because arrays have variable values but constant pointers.  But for strings, we write
>   `const char *s;`.

I don't understand why. Is this correct? Do strings really have constant values and variable pointers in C?

Comment: `const char *s` makes `s` a pointer to constant characters. I.e. it's a string which can not be modified. So ask yourself this: Do you want to modify the characters in the string or not? When you can answer that then you will know if `const` is needed or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So can I declare an string in the way of `char *const s;`?

Comment: If you mean "define string" as `const char *s = "asdf";` then `s` is pointing to a string literal and modifying it leads to undefined behavior. Therefore you should declare it as const.

Comment: The difference is, that const char *s would be a pointer to const char, while char *const s would be a const pointer to char. I suggest you read: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: Again *it depends on what you want to do*. With `char * const s;` you declare a variable `s` which is a constant pointer, once you initialize it you can not make `s` point anywhere else. Is that what you want? And note that you can do `const char * const s;` as well, for a constant pointer to constant data.

Comment: "*can I declare an string in the way of `char *const s;`*" being picky: No, as this defines a pointer (not a "string"), a constant pointer to *a* `char` or to the 1st `char` of a sequence of `char`s, to the 1st element of a `char` array. In C a "string" is a `char` ***array*** containing (at least) one `'\0'`.  A `char` array is *not* a pointer, but ... well ... an array.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following:

```
char* a;
char* const b = "Hello"
const char* c;
const char* const d = "world";
```

`a` just points to a character. That might be the first character of a string, or a single byte. That character can be modified by writing `*a='Z'` or `a[0]='q'` or by passing `a` to a function taking a `char*` parameter. The pointer itself can also be modified to point at some other characters, e.g. `a=b;` or `a="foo";`. This is the most flexible form, and the least safe, because you can do anything with it.

`b` is a constant pointer to a character. In this case, it's pointing at an array of characters. Those characters can be modified, e.g. `b[1]='a';` or `*b=0;` but `b` itself is constant, meaning that it cannot ever point at a different part of memory. This form may be used when you have allocated a buffer or array whose contents you want to modify, but which cannot move, since it was allocated by the operating system.

`c` points to a constant character. You can change what it points at (`c="foo";` or `c=b;`) but you cannot use this pointer to change the characters that it points at -- *even if it's pointing at the non-constant buffer* `b`. This form is commonly used when handling pre-generated strings. You can use this variable to store strings you've found, and pass their address around, as long as you don't change the strings themselves.

`d` is a constant pointer to a constant character. You can't change the characters it's pointing at, and you can't point the pointer itself at a different memory location. All you can do is read the string or individual characters (`char e=d[4];` or `puts(d);`). This form is mainly used when passing around reference strings, for example when naming real objects.

Comment: I'm afraid the last definition is just redundant: `const char const* d` is strictly equivalent to `const char *d` and `char const *d`. For `d` to be a constant pointer to a constant character, you must define it as `const char * const d;` or `char const * const d;`.

Comment: Correctd. Thanks.

Comment: OK, the answer is corrected, but advocating the use of `const` pointer variables as *commonly used* is not really helpful. Cases where this is needed are vanishingly rare. Tagging local variables as `const` obfuscates the code without any advantages.

Comment: I have attempted to clarify the wording. The intent wasn't to suggest that this form was common, but that when this form is used, it is usually for reference material.

Comment: OK, but I still frown upon *mainly used*. This form is almost never used, except for overly restrictive coding conventions and people that are not aware of its exact semantics. Reference strings can be passed and handled with regular `const char *` pointers. Have you actually used this form and/or the second one?

Answer (score 4):

Code such as `int *const a;` is nonsense in most use-cases. The main use of making a pointer `const` is when you have a pointer-based look-up table. Or when you want a pointer to be stored in read-only memory on an embedded system.

Some confused programmers like to write code like `void func (int* const ptr)` but this is only obfuscation, in my opinion, since `ptr` is a copy of the original pointer anyhow, and the caller couldn't care less what the function does with its local copy internally.

Not to be mixed up with *const correctness*, which means that pointers to read-only data should be declared as `const int* ptr`. This is widely recognized as good programming practice, and it is canonical C, since most of the C standard utilizes const correctness for the C standard library.

As for pointers to *string literals* (like `"hello"`) specifically, they should be declared `const char* ptr = "hello";` for the reason that modifying a string literal invokes undefined behavior. Meaning that modifying it is a bug and might cause a program crash. This is a known flaw in C - the type of the string literal itself, even though we aren't allowed to write to it, is `char[]`. This is for historical reasons. In C++ however, they have fixed this language flaw inherited from C, so all string literals are `const char[]` in C++.

Comment: To be a bad one, I prefer `char const *` ;) and I think that you force your point of view about make variable itself const, there is nothing confusing in `void func (int* const ptr)`

Comment: @Stargateur Do you also write `extern const int func (const int param x, const int param y)`? It's the very same argument.

Comment: No it's not, your exemple is completely different. 1. Because mut is default in C so const is needed contrary to extern 2. const on the return type of a function is ignored contrary to const on a parameter variable

Answer (score 2):

1. When you use this statement

   ```
   char *str = "Stack Overflow";
   ```

   it means that `str` points to string `"Stack Overflow"`, which is stored in code memory and user is not allowed to modify it. So for this statement, writing `const` before `char *str` doesn't have any effect because the string is already constant.

   But `const` plays important role when you are pointing towards the base address of array, like

   ```
   char arr[20];
   strcpy(arr,"Stack Overflow");
   const char *str = arr;
   ```

   Use of `const` means you can't modify the string in `arr` through the pointer `str`.
2. When you are using

   ```
   char * const ptr;
   ```

   it means that `ptr` can't point to another address other than it's initial address. It is used when you do not intend to change the pointer address throughout the entire program, e.g. pointing to look up tables in embedded systems.

Comment: *"writing `const` before `char *str` doesn't have any effect"* This is not true.

Comment: _"writing `const` before `char *str` doesn't have anny effect"_  This is false.  If you put `const char *str` the compiler will disallow you to modify the string, giving a compile time error.  Not doing that is undefined behaviour, as depending on the architecture you'll succeed modifying read-only strings, or you'll fail with a possible exception on trying to write read only memory.